# Jquery input phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

i had a normal input box, but i want to made a validation on keypress.

so the input must starting with 08 or +62 and length must be minimum of 8 and max is 14

here's my code on jquery.

```
$(".PhoneVal").keyup(function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
var val = $this.val();
var size = $this.val().length;
// console.log(size);
if (size != 2) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(val);
}
else if (size = 2 && val != 08) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val('');
    $.notify({
        // options
        message: 'Invalid Number, use starting with 08 or +628' 
      },{
        // settings
        type: 'warning',
        allow_dismiss: true,
        delay: 2000,
        z_index: 2000
      });

}

if (size > 14) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val();
    $.notify({
        // options
        message: 'Invalid length of number' 
      },{
        // settings
        type: 'warning',
        allow_dismiss: true,
        delay: 2000,
        z_index: 2000
      });
  }
```

also i want to made if its typed more than 14, then it should show notify and cant be typed anymore or the length stop at 14.

in this code, i only can validate if the number should start with 08, i dont know how to made with +62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate, if the string contains sub-substrig.

You could also check, if your `val` variable starts with *+62*, which is better than just testing it, against the sub-string with `indexOf` method.

To do that, just run:

```
val.startsWith('+62')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `indexOf` method, something like this:

```
if(val.indexOf('+62') === 0){ 
     // this means the word have the number at the beginning
}
```

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev making the test at the console, what you say is not happening, Why do you say that `1231231+62+62` would pass the test, in this case this returns 7